# How to run two indefinite Xcode playgrounds simultaneously

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, multipeer-connectivity

I am playing around with the MultipeerConnectivity library and created a couple swift Xcode playgrounds to spin up and work on some test code. Each playground runs without error on its own, but when I start the second playground the other immediately stops and I am unable to test my connectivity code. Is it possible to run two playgrounds simultaneously? If so, how do you accomplish this? My playgrounds are below.

Server Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import MultipeerConnectivity
import PlaygroundSupport

let serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: MCPeerID(displayName: "server"), discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "MCTest")
serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Client Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import MultipeerConnectivity
import PlaygroundSupport

class Client: NSObject, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {
    let serviceBrowser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser

    override init() {
        serviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: MCPeerID(displayName: "client"), serviceType: "MCTest")
        super.init()
        serviceBrowser.delegate = self
        serviceBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        NSLog("foundPeer: \(peerID)")
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        NSLog("lostPeer: \(peerID)")
    }
}

let myClient = Client()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: What version of Xcode? What is the playground target (iOS or macOS)?

Comment: Xcode version 9.0 (9A235), Blank iOS playground target.

Comment: Under the hood, I am pretty sure that the view is run in a simulator. Xcode 9 supports multiple sims running at the same time, but I guess not in Playgrounds.

Comment: If the library runs on macOS, I'd try making one of the playgrounds into a mac one.

Comment: @LouFranco Thanks for thinking outside the box! Your solution works for my specific use case where the library I am playing with is on iOS and MacOS. It would be nice if Apple allowed multiple playgrounds for a single OS type.